# How can I get a polyline or geometry coordinates for municipality in map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, leaflet, laravel-8

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);

})
```

and this is the sample data I got from internet that works. But what I want is the municipality of the Philippines.

```
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}
]};
```

I've tried using leaflet.js and googlemap and openstreetmap for my map interface

Comment: Please include the reference for `L`.  People can't debug things if they don't know what they are.

Comment: It's a default function in leaflet.js

Comment: Saying "you tried leaflet" implies that you're not now using leaflet, and it wasn't in your tags.  No-one knows every JS component that exists, help us help you.  Your question needs to be a [mre] so people don't have to guess what things like `L` are.

Comment: Leaflet is just a package to show tile maps, it does not know every location, it just show the maps and coordinates you provide it with. Would say that this is a geo search question rather than a Leaflet question. Since you already use OSM for the tile maps you could have a look att OSM geo search project 
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html
Note that this project is only made for testing and not production, you will probably end up using a paid geo search api if you want to use this in production